# Sublime text 2 adds and removes blank lines on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, editor, sublimetext2, specifications

I am using Sublime Text 2 and it is great.

I use it to write html, css and ruby.

I have a problem when I edit my spec files, because it adds and removes blank lines in the whole file and makes the git log unreadable.

[this is the git diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65LS4.png)

Comment: We are only two developers the other one uses geany, and he does not have the same problem. What did you say that I needed to turn off? Thanks!

Comment: Open your settings (Settings - User) and add/change the entry `"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": false,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your editor is configured to remove trailing whitespace and other developers in the team don't use that setting. Or vise versa. they remove whitespace and you don't.

Therefore I suggest to use the same settings in the whole team.

To enable or disable that feature, go to `SublimeText 2 > Preferences > User Settings` and add

```
  "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
```

or

```
  "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": false
```

to the configuration